# SSMS Find matching parenthesis Highlighting Feature aka Brace Matching Half Broken - How to Fix

Tags: ssms

SSMS version 19.1

This feature also takes on the name of Automatic Matching of Syntax Pairs.  Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/automatic-matching-of-syntax-pairs?view=sql-server-ver16).  This feature for me however is failing to function as expected.

I used to be able to **use my mouse** and click a parenthesis in SSMS and it would highlight the matching begin/end parenthesis however it is no longer doing that.  In my troubleshooting I discovered that the only method I have to activate the highlighting feature is to use the arrow keys on my keyboard however this ONLY works on parenthesis.

There is also the highlighting feature of highlighting the begin/end of the BEGIN END blocks and also BEGIN TRY/END TRY BEGIN CATCH/END CATCH.  This highlighting feature I can only get to work if I remove the last character and retype it.  It is only then that SSMS will highlight these syntax pairs.

What am I doing wrong?  This feature was certainly not designed to behave this way.  If this is the expected behavior I'm not a fan and would say it was half implemented.

Again, please let me know if there is a way to have the highlighting of syntax pairs just work when using my mouse when clicking on them in SSMS.

#### Screenshot below of mock SQL and the settings for Brace Matching in Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Fonts and Colors:

[image: Brace Matching Screenshots]

#### Gif showing that I can only get it to work when using the keyboard and for the Keywords to match up I show that I can only get it to highlight if I first Delete the last letter in the Keyword

[image: Gif Showing Syntax Pair Highlighting Half Broken]

Comment: To be honest, this issue has been spotty as long as I can remember for the last 10 years.